# Autocomplete function with multiple input type, dinamically inserted

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm trying to make an autocomplete using sql, php, javascript, using dinamically inserted lines on a table.

The point is that the autocomplete is working for the first line but not working for the lines I add after.

My HTML to add lines:

```
<table class='ui striped table inverted'>
   <tr align="center">
      <td>Contacto</td>
   </tr>
   <tr align="center" class="linhas">
      <td>
         <div class="ui input">
            <input type="text" id = "contacto" />
         </div>
      </td>
      <td><a href="#" class="removerCampo" title="Remover linha">Remover</a></td>
   </tr>
</table>
<tr>
   <td colspan="2"><a href="#" class="adicionarCampo" title="Adicionar item">Adicionar linha</a></td>
</tr>
```

My Javascript script for the add lines dinamically:

```
$(function () {
           function removeCampo() {
            $(".removerCampo").unbind("click");
            $(".removerCampo").bind("click", function () {
               if($("tr.linhas").length > 1){
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
               }
            });
           }

           $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {

            novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();  

            novoCampo.find("input").val("");

            novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");

            removeCampo();
           });
         });
      </script>
```

My Javascript script for the autocomplete:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

      function log( message ) {
            $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
            $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
      }

      $("#contacto").autocomplete({
            source: "searchContactos.php",
            minLength: 3,
            select: function(event,ui) {
                  log(ui.item ?
                        "Selected: " + ui.item.value :
                        "Nothing selected input was " + this.value);
            }
      });


});
</script>
```

My php file:

```
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
  $autoCompleteResult = array();

  $tsql = "SELECT no_, name FROM [Master].[dbo].[Contactos Portal] WHERE name 
           LIKE '$term' or no_ LIKE '$term' ";
  $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);

  while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
     array_push($autoCompleteResult,array("value" => $row['name'] .' -> '. 
     $row['no_'] ));
  }

sqlsrv_close($conn);
echo json_encode($autoCompleteResult);
}
```

I expected the autocomplete to work for as many lines as I inserted. Only working for the first line. Can someone please point me the right direction?

This is the process. The autocomplete only works on the first line on square #1. On #4 it does not work.

[image: Process]

Thank you very much.

Comment: "not working for the lines I add after." - what is it actually doing when it doesn't work? Error messages, funky HTML behavior, etc?

Comment: It also might help if you explain the process & specifically where in that process that it breaks.

Comment: Thank you all. I added the process on the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I see two things:

1. You are selecting your input with an ID, implying that there should only be one. But because you expect the user to add several `#Contacto`, I would say assigning a *class* `.Contacto` (and selecting on that) makes more sense.
2. When you `clone()` your input box, you aren't including the event listener you attached to the first one. `clone()` has an [overload](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) that lets you include those attached event listeners. You should be able to use `clone(true)` to copy not just the input, but the autocomplete functionality as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right about topic #1. I've changed to class instead of id. However It still doesn't work.

Tried also to "addClass" but with no success. 
     $("tr.linhas:first").clone(true).addClass("contacto").insertAfter("tr.linhas:last").find("input").val("");

Comment: You might find it simpler to debug if you remove the table layout. By copying/inserting table rows when functionally you're only trying to add a new input, you're complicating the issue and causing yourself a lot of headaches. You'll save yourself a lot of trouble if you offload the styling to CSS and clone the input directly.

Comment: No lucky. Still can't clone class .contacto!